# Why do i have to put "-g" on npm install command?

Tags: express, npm

I am new to node.js, everything is running fine right now for me, but i am interested in something, on all tutorials i have seen, it is simple to install packages, for example, when they install express, they write:

```
npm install express
```

but in my console, i have to write

```
npm install express -g
```

The first one gives me error while trying to install the package. Is this caused  because i have installed windows and i use command prompt?

Comment: Low quality: You get an error but what is it? Did the manual help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install express as a global package, you need to add `-g` param.

If you don't use the `-g` param, you will need to install express for every local node_modules folder.

For more information, please check https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: -g stands for global. You can also use -global, it is the same as -g